# What do I do if a contributed module update is not available?

Tags: 7, migrations

I am upgrading a project from D6 to D7, and I've noticed that some contributed modules I need is not available as stable D7 releases. Some contributed modules are not at all available for D7, and some contributed modules only exists as development releases for D7.

Example: The [OneHourTranslation Service](https://drupal.org/project/one_hour_translations) module.  It doesn't have a D7 version, not even a development release.

1. What should I do if the module I need is not available for the upgraded D7 version?
2. What should I do if the module is only available as a development release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the safer approach is not to update to Drupal 7 and wait until all modules have at least a beta version for D7. If there are modules which do not have a D7 version at all, you can try to get a developer to convert the module(s) to D7

Comment: Or, if you're going to pay someone to do it anyway, contact the module developer and ask if you can sponsor the development. You'll probably get your company logo and a link on the module page, and you'll get the module fixed - everyone wins

Comment: Even better:  Contribute to the D7 upgrade yourself :)